# OpenVPN does not work on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking, vpn

I first downloaded openvpn via:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

then I used VPNBook .ovpn file to connect:

```
sudo openvpn vpnbook-euro2-udp2500.ovpn
```

it says 'Initialization Sequence Completed', but nothing goes through the proxy.
I used the same steps on Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows (with OpenVPN GUI) and it worked.

Are there any extra steps I need to do on Raspberry Pi?

---

**Edit:**
ifconfig:

```
tun2: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.10.0.246  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.0.245
    inet6 fe80::dfb0:256e:6138:1100  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 373  bytes 417813 (408.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 423  bytes 36411 (35.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.90  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::d947:5974:372b:7800  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:9c:00:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5776  bytes 1430024 (1.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 9577  bytes 8658660 (8.2 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.245     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun2
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.10.0.1       10.10.0.245     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun2
10.10.0.245     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun2
128.0.0.0       10.10.0.245     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun2
176.126.237.214 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: It will be easier to fix with more information, openvpn log, openvpn config file, output of `ifconfig` and `route -n`. Please add them to your question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it!

It was DNS leak.

I edited /etc/resolv.conf and replaced

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

with:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

which is for OpenDNS, and things are working now.